# plotというPythonライブラリでModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

「[行列プログラマー](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117775/)」という書籍で以下のようなコードが出てきましたが、この通りにやると`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotting'`というエラーが出ます。

このライブラリーはもう使えないのでしょうか。
それともライブラリーを呼び出すのが間違っているのでしょうか

**コード**

```py
>>>from plotting import plot

>>> S = S ={2+2j,3+2j,1.75+1j,2+1j,2.25+1j,2.5+1j,2.75+1j,3+1j,3.25+1j}

>>> plot(S,4)
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```py
>>>from plotting import plot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotting'
```

Answer (score 2):

それは著者が作成したモジュールで、書籍のサイトからダウンロードするものじゃないですか?

http://resources.codingthematrix.com/ を見るとplotting.pyほかいくつかのファイルがあります。

Answer (score 0):

Pythonでplotというと、pyplotモジュールのplot関数が有名です。（インストール方法などは、[【Python入門】plot関数でグラフを作成してみよう！](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/54287)　などの記事を参照してください）

```
S ={2+2j,3+2j,1.75+1j,2+1j,2.25+1j,2.5+1j,2.75+1j,3+1j,3.25+1j}
```

Pythonで {}はディクショナリを表すのに使われます。上記のコードは、Sに複素数のリストを代入するものだと思われますので

```
S =[2+2j,3+2j,1.75+1j,2+1j,2.25+1j,2.5+1j,2.75+1j,3+1j,3.25+1j]
```

ではないでしょうか？　( {}ではなく、[]を使っています）

複素数のリストですので、x軸を実数部、y軸を虚数部としてプロットする等の工夫が必要だと思います。

Comment: 本筋でないですが，コロンのない `{ }` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays)) は [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)です